# How to use Bootstrap grid system to div?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing the asp.net bootstrap form. I have one div in it.

[image]

Code:

```
<div id="gallery">
        <a href="aboutus.aspx">
            <img src="images/layout/exportsatdubai.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="900" title="" alt="" rel="a" />
        </a>

         <a href="http://expogr.com/" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/layout/777x282-africa-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="900" title="" alt="" rel="a" />
        </a>
        <a href="addlisting.aspx">
            <img src="images/layout/becomeAMember.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="900" title="" alt="" rel="a" />
        </a><a href="dubaiexhibitions.aspx">
            <img src="images/layout/dubaiexportersexhibitions.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="1000" title="" alt=""
                rel="a" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
  #gallery
        {
            position: relative;
            height: 282px;
        }
```

I wanted to make this div responsive using Bootstrap grid system. I am confused with div ie. How to apply grid system on div?

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="gallery">
       ------contents------
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is it like this? I am new to Bootstrap. I just wanted to know how to apply grid system to div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bootstrap grid like this.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <a href="aboutus.aspx">
         <img src="images/layout/exportsatdubai.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" rel="a" />
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <a href="http://expogr.com/" target="_blank">
         <img src="images/layout/777x282-africa-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" rel="a" />
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <a href="addlisting.aspx">
         <img src="images/layout/becomeAMember.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" rel="a" />
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <a href="dubaiexhibitions.aspx">
         <img src="images/layout/dubaiexportersexhibitions.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" rel="a" />
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can follow this link for further details. [Bootstrap Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Answer (score 0):

A general way to use grid system is

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3">Content1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Content2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Content3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Content4</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Every column will have equal width and it will act responsive. You don't need to set height or width of divs inside these columns unless you intentionally want it. If you can provide more details what exactly do you want , i can try to help more.

Comment: @prashant.....http://dubaiexporters.com/Default.aspx....i am trying to make right image  responsive...

Comment: Just remove the width form image and let im-responsive class handle the responsiveness

Answer (score 0):

you can use the grid system of 12 spans and as many rows as you want  as you have different spanning of images for different rows  like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"></div>
  <a href="aboutus.aspx">
         <img src="images/layout/exportsatdubai.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
         </a>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">...</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">.....</div>
</div>

..... 
.....
and so on
</div>
```